# Returning a Tuple in Python function

Tags: python

This function that I have written thus:

```
def simulate_turn(num_rolls, score, opponent_score):
    """This function takes in two scores and a number of die rolls and returns
    what the two scores would be if num_rolls many dice were rolled. This takes
    into account the swine swap, free bacon, and hog-wild."""
    x = score
    y = opponent_score
    x += take_turn(num_rolls,opponent_score,select_dice(score,opponent_score))
    if ifwillswap(x,y):
        swap(x,y)
    return x,y
```

When run in the interactive python shell (the function comes from a .py file), it is returning an int object instead of a tuple! What am I doing wrong? I am trying to have it turn a pair of values, not a single int object.

Comment: provide your IDLE transcript so we can see exactly what's going on

Comment: I just mocked up this function, replacing `take_turn` and other undefined things with `lambda *a: 1`. It returns a tuple. (There's no way this function shown is returning anything other than a tuple. That `return` statement returns a tuple.)

Comment: What int object is it returning? The value of `x` or the value of `y`?

Comment: There's no way `swap` works. (Are you taking CS61A at UCB?)

Comment: "it is returning an int object instead of a tuple! " - I don't believe that.

Answer (score 1):

You already do return a pair of values. Even if you somehow broke `x` and `y` somewhere along the way and had something ridiculous like this:

```
def example():
    return None, None
a = example()
```

`a` would still hold a reference to the tuple `(None, None)` after the execution of that function. So you are returning a tuple of two *"somethings"*, the only question is what are those "somethings" and how you are storing them. There is no reason for you to think that your function returns an `int` however, because it doesn't. No matter what, with the syntax you've used, your function returns a tuple of two types. You could even just do `return x,` and that would return a one-item tuple. The comma prevents you from returning just an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your function swap() is maybe setting your variable y equal to None and that you are perhaps misinterpreting the returned values.  As others have said, I don't see how you can see anything but a tuple as the return.

Answer (score -2):

```
from typing import Tuple
(int,int)-> Tuple
(int,str)_.Tuple
```

By using this code from above you can return a `tuple`.

I am using the `Tuple` function which works well. Hope this helps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).